# saving new position of table row jquery ui sortable, MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

i want to allows users to sort table rows derived from database and save the new location in database
**the problem is that the postion is not updated in the interface nither in the database**
mysql table: `id int primary key auto_increment, sort int, author_affliation varchar, author_email varchar`

script:

```
$('#myTable tbody').sortable({
                    start: function (event, ui) {
                        //fix firefox position issue when dragging.
                        if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/firefox/) && ui.helper !== undefined) {
                            ui.helper.css('position', 'absolute').css('margin-top', $(window).scrollTop());
                            //wire up event that changes the margin whenever the window scrolls.
                            $(window).bind('scroll.sortableplaylist', function () {
                                ui.helper.css('position', 'absolute').css('margin-top', $(window).scrollTop());
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
                        //undo the firefox fix.
                        if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/firefox/) && ui.offset !== undefined) {
                            $(window).unbind('scroll.sortableplaylist');
                            ui.helper.css('margin-top', 0);
                        }
                    },
                    helper: function (e, ui) {
                        ui.children().each(function () {
                            $(this).width($(this).width());
                        });
                        return ui;
                    },
                    scroll: true,
                    update: function (event, ui) {
                        serial = $(this).sortable('serialize');
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "sort_coauthors.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: serial,
                            success: function(response) {
                              alert(response);
                            },
                            error: function(){
                                alert("theres an error with AJAX");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).disableSelection();
```

sort-coauthors:

```
@mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb") or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['menu']) && is_array( $_POST['menu'])) {
$menu = $_POST['menu'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($menu); $i++) {
    $q = mysql_query("UPDATE `co_authors` SET `sort`=" . $i . " WHERE `id`='" . intval($menu[$i]) . "'") or die(mysql_error());
if($q) {
    echo "success";
}
}
}
else {
    echo "fail";
}
```

main page:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($co_authors)) {

                    echo "<tbody><tr id='menu_" . $row['id'] . "'><td>{$row['author_email']}</td>
                     <td>{$row['coauthor_affliation']}</td>";
                    ?><td><button class='remove' id='remove' name='remove' email="<?php echo $row['author_email'] ?>"
                            paper="<?php echo $row['paper_id'] ?>">Remove</button></td>
```

Comment: Does the sql used in the main page sort records? ("ORDER BY sort ASC")
Does the alert says "success"?
Can you verify the data passed in the ajax request? (I mean, with Firebug or similar, or dumping $_POST in sort_coauthors.php)